# Go through every pixel of an image and then dispose of it

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm a little confused as to whether implementing the `Dispose` method serves a purpose in this code. It never gets referenced by any other class in my project, so should I simply get rid of it or should I make an explicit call to `Dispose` when releasing the bitmap image?

```
namespace ImageProcessor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A bitmap class that allows fast x, y access
        /// </summary>
        public unsafe class UnsafeBitmap
        {
            Bitmap source;
            int width;
            BitmapData bmpData = null;
            IntPtr baseLine = IntPtr.Zero;
            BGRA* pCurrentPixel = null;
            Point size;
            internal bool locked = false;

            /// <summary>
            /// Create an instance from an existing bitmap
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="src">The source bitmap</param>
            public UnsafeBitmap(Bitmap src)
            {
                source = src;
                GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                RectangleF boundsF = src.GetBounds(ref units);
                size = new Point((int)boundsF.Width, (int)boundsF.Height);
            }

            public Bitmap Bitmap
            {
                get { return (source); }
                set { source = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Lock bitmap data
            /// </summary>
            public void LockBitmap()
            {
                try
                {
                    GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                    RectangleF boundsF = source.GetBounds(ref units);
                    Rectangle bounds = Rectangle.Round(boundsF);

                    // For a standard BMP, each individual scan line needs to be a multiple 
                    // of 4 bytes, so when we have a 24 bit image (3 bytes per pixel),
                    // we need to allow for padding at the end of every scan line
                    // to bring it up to a multiple of 4.
                    width = (int)boundsF.Width * sizeof(BGRA);
                    if (width % 4 != 0)
                        width = 4 * (width / 4 + 1);

                    // Lock the bitmap's bits
                    bmpData = source.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                    // Get the address of the first line
                    //pBase = (Byte*)bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                    baseLine = bmpData.Scan0;
                    locked = true;
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Unlock bitmap data
            /// </summary>

            public void UnlockBitmap()
            {
                try
                {
                    source.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                    bmpData = null;
                    baseLine = IntPtr.Zero;
                    locked = false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                source.Dispose();
            }

            public Point GetSize
            {
                get { return size; }
            }

            public BGRA* this[int x, int y]
            {
                get
                {
                    return (BGRA*)(baseLine + y * width + x * sizeof(BGRA));
                }
            }
        }
```

Any other comments are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I think your `Bitmap` property shouldn't have a setter. If you use it, you don't dispose the old `Bitmap` and you don't reset `size`. Both seem to be erroneous to me.

---

```
public Bitmap Bitmap
{
    get { return (source); }
    set { source = value; }
}
```

Why is `source` in parentheses?

Also, this could be an auto-property. You would then use the (possibly `private`) setter instead of the field in the constructor.

---

```
catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

This doesn't do anything, get rid of it.

---

```
public BGRA* this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        return (BGRA*)(baseLine + y * width + x * sizeof(BGRA));
    }
}
```

If the type of `baseLine` was `BGRA*` (and you also changed `width` not to include the size), then the `return` statement could be simplified to:

```
return &baseLine[y * width + x];
```

Also, I would consider returning `BGRA` directly, I think that's more natural (assuming doing that doesn't decrease performance noticeably).

Answer (score 2):

So your class has the `source` member which should be disposed, but this object is not created by your object, it is passed in via the constructor or the setter.  If you dispose of it, that Bitmap will no longer be usable.  Is there a use case where someone using your class would want to keep using that bitmap, even after they are done with your object?  If so, then you shouldn't dispose of it, and that should be the responsibility of the creator.  The technical term is if your class implements "ownership semantics" - that is, if it takes over ownership of the passed in bitmap.

From looking at the code I want to say that ownership isn't appropriate here, which means that you shouldn't dispose the source bitmap, which means you don't need to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: That source bitmap parameter, that I pass in, changes after every single iteration so no one would want to keep using the old one. That means I should take care to explicitly dispose of it, if I understood you right?

Comment: You changing the bitmap each iteration doesn't make much difference if you are comparing `foreach (var bmp in GetBmps()) using (var ubmp = new UnsafeBitmap(bmp)){}` vs `foreach (var bmp in GetBmps()) using (bmp){var ubmp = new UnsafeBitmap(bmp);}`  You're just switching around what goes in the using statement or what is explicitly disposed.

Comment: It's a judgement call, and it really requires that you consider all of the ways people might want to use your class.  If you are the only one using it then there isn't really a wrong answer, just do whatever is easiest.  If there are others, how will they use it, and should it destroy their bitmaps?

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt need to be done, i was at the same point in my code today.
The reason why you lock it is because you want to lock a memory area for direct access, ea disable Compiler checks, do all kinda "wrong" things that normally wouldnt be allowed by the compiler.

You dont want to get rid of the locked data (ea Dispose it), instead your code only needs to release the object for normal access again. Essentially one doesnt create a new bitmap when one locks an image. And so no new data is created no new data needs to be disposed